# Hibernate insert default datetime to a not null column

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

In my table I have a column with following definition.

```
createdat DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
```

I'm trying to insert data in to this table using hibernate. I want this column to have default value. But it gives me exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'createdat' cannot be null

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to change `DEFAULT NOW()` to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. MySQL currently [does not support default values with functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html). It might be a scalar value, but not a function.

Comment: This is a well-known problem.  You may have to lie to Hibernate and tell it the column is nullable even though in the database it's not.  I haven't found a way to prevent Hibernate from being "too helpful" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just initiate your date object with new Date object in your POJO which is mapped in hibernate.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
```

I suppose you have your setters and getter for POJO, whenever you forgot or dont want to set date object this default date will be used